# Unable to resolve property '%1' while processing properties for Uid '%0'

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I'm trying to localize my WP 8.1 app.

Here is a part of `Strings/en-us/Resources.resw`:

```xml
<data name="SampleProperty.Text" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Sample text</value>
</data>
<data name="SampleProperty.SomeRandomKey" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>SAMPLE TEXT</value>
</data>
```

Also one of application pages contains the following code:

```xml
<TextBlock x:Uid="SampleProperty" />
```

But the app throws an exception in process of navigation to that page:

```
WinRT information: Unable to resolve property '%1' while processing properties for Uid '%0'. [Line: 167 Position: 24]
Additional information: The text associated with this error code could not be found.
```

If I remove `SampleProperty.SomeRandomKey` from the resource dictionary then all works fine. But this string is used in another part of my app.

Where can be the problem?

**UPD**

I've added properties like in the sample from [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965329.aspx):

```xml
<data name="SampleProperty.Text" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Sample text</value>
</data>
<data name="SampleProperty.Width" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>0</value>
</data>
```

All works fine.
But I can't understand why this works and why the first case gives the exception...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear what "SomeRandomKey" is in your example, and what you are trying to achieve with it.
But this exception is thrown because TextBlocks don't have a SomeRandomKey property.
They have Text, Width, but definitely not "SomeRandomKey". Just remove it.

Comment: Documentation doesn't provide clear information that for a string resource all keys provided after dot (Text, Width etc.) must have corresponding properties on the control side, and that otherwise exception will be thrown. It wasn't obvious. So I think you answer my question. Thanks!